# Всплывающее уведомление для TG-Бота

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Коллеги, всем привет! Пишу телеграм бота на JS.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вот такое уведомление?

[image: Уведомление, которое меня интересует]

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery

Comment: @ИванИпатов, ты скинул ссылку на методы, позволяющие создать уведомление https://disk.yandex.ru/i/xQl9_hu7J10jdA , но мне требуется другое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете node-telegram-bot-api, то вот

```js
bot.on('callback_query', (query) => {
    bot.answerCallbackQuery(query.id, {text: 'Просто отправь боту фотографию', show_alert: true});
});
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе! )

Comment: Не за что =) )))